# possibility of Building TensorFlow for Graphic cards of lower compute capability(less than 3.0)

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

As it is well known, TensorFlow needs at least compute capability higher than 3.5 to use gpu accelerations.

in hardware requirements mentioned in tensorflow.org, it was stated that :

```
For GPUs with unsupported CUDA® architectures, or to avoid JIT 
compilation from PTX, or to use different versions of the NVIDIA® 
libraries, see the Linux build from source guide.
```

I have seen several cases which build tensorflow for graphic card of 3.0 compute capability(cc).
I am eager to know does this method work for lower cc(=2.2) like Nvidia Quadro 1000M?

Thanks in advance